# How to make flexbox children match the height of the first child with dynamic height?

Tags: css, flexbox

Say I have a flexbox with 3 elements:

First child has 4-7 lines.
Second child has 40-50 lines.
Third child has 2-5 lines.

I want to set the second child's height to match the same as the first child.

I know I can set the `height: 300px` or some static value, but the content might be shorter or longer.

Here's an example (I want the second child [green box] to be the same height of the first child [purple box]:

[image: flexbox example]

I've tried several ways unsuccessfully (like flex-shrink). Here's part of the code:

I have considered using js to get the height of the first child and applying it to the parent, but is there a way to do this via css only?

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.child {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  // height: 300px; // this works but then the height would not match the first child's
}

.child1 {
  display: flex;
  background: purple;
}

.child2 {
  background: green;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child3 {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1 child">
    This div has dynamic amount of lines... <br>line 1 <br> line 2 <br/>line 3 <br> line 4 <br> line 5<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="child2 child">
    This div has a lot of lines... <br>line 1 <br> line 2 <br/>line 3 <br> line 4 <br> line 5<br/> line 6 <br> line 7 <br/>line 8 <br> line 9 <br> line ...<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="child3 child">
    some other div <br> 1 <br>2 <br/> 3 <br> 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with modifying your HTML structure a little bit, here's a solution with relatively little changes:

1. Wrap the contents of `child2` and `child3` in another div, let's say `wrapper`.

```html
<div class="child2 child">
  <div class="wrapper">
    This div has a lot of lines... <br>line 1 <br> line 2 <br/>line 3 <br> line 4 <br> line 5<br/> line 6 <br> line 7 <br/>line 8 <br> line 9 <br> line ...<br/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="child3 child">
  <div class="wrapper">
    some other div <br> 1 <br>2 <br/> 3 <br> 4
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Make `wrapper` `position: absolute`, so the heights are only determined by children that doesn't have a `wrapper`, which is `child1`. And then make them `scroll: auto`.

```css
.child {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's the full solution:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.child {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child1 {
  display: flex;
  background: purple;
}

.child2 {
  background: green;
  min-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.child3 {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1 child">
    This div has dynamic amount of lines... <br>line 1 <br> line 2 <br/>line 3 <br> line 4 <br> line 5<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="child2 child">
    <div class="wrapper">
    This div has a lot of lines... <br>line 1 <br> line 2 <br/>line 3 <br> line 4 <br> line 5<br/> line 6 <br> line 7 <br/>line 8 <br> line 9 <br> line ...<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child3 child">
    <div class="wrapper">
      some other div <br> 1 <br>2 <br/> 3 <br> 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```